# How can I interrupt a loop on a MySQL query when the are no affected rows?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have an array of objects I need to loop through.
For every object I need to perform a MySQL `INSERT IGNORE` type of query.
The problem is I have to stop looping as I see that the data I get from one of the objects present in the array already exists in the DB checking the `affectedRows` property on the `results` object that comes with mysql.

```
cont arrayOfObjects = [{foo: foo, bar: bar}, {foo: foo1, bar: bar1}];

for(obj of arrayOfObjects){
   let sql = `INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name VALUES(${obj.foo}, ${obj.bar});`;
   connection.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
       if(results[0].affectedRows === 0){
           // I want to stop looping
       }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so, you can run update operations one by one and checking the result.

For example :

```
async function runUpdates() {
  const arrayOfObjects = [{foo: foo, bar: bar}, {foo: foo1, bar: bar1}];
  const needToStop = false;
  for (const obj of arrayOfObjects) {
     if (!needToStop) {
        const updated = await runQuery(obj);
        if (updated > 0) { needToStop = true; }
     }
  }
  return 'OK';
}



function runQuery(obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let sql = `INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name VALUES(${obj.foo},${obj.bar});`;
     connection.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
         if (error) { return reject(error);}
         resolve(results[0].affectedRows);
     });
 })
}
```

Comment: A little over-kill for when query returns a call-back on completion every-time, yikes! Don't double promise up, this is way too much code for the task.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function CallMeMaybe() {
                connection.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
                    if (results[0].affectedRows === 0) {
                        // I want to stop looping
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            CallMeMaybe();
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                });  
}
CallMeMaybe();
```

I'd not be looping it but calling it if the condition is met--AGAIN!

Comment: To elaborate, the query call is promised, there's a call-back in the function correct?
So if you await its finish and repeat off that when result is positive it'd work flawless. So just function wrap it and repeat call the function based on my example above and see how it goes, no need to double promise things; just locks out the event-loop... AKA lag.